# Read binary data as Lua number with FFI

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I have a file I opened as binary like this:  `local dem = io.open("testdem.dem", "rb")`
I can read out strings from it just fine: `print(dem:read(8))` -> `HL2DEMO`, however, afterwards there is a 4-byte little endian integer and a 4-byte float (docs for the file format don't specify endianess but since it didn't specify little like the integer I'll have to assume big).
This cannot be read out with `read`.
I am new to the LuaJIT FFI and am not sure how to read this out. Frankly, I find the documentation on this specific aspect of the FFI to be underwhelming, although I'm just a lua programmer and don't have much experience with C. One thing I have tried is creating a cdata, but I don't think I understand that:

```lua
local dem = io.open("testdem.dem", "rb")
print(dem:read(8))
local cd = ffi.new("int", 4)
ffi.copy(cd, dem:read(4), 4)
print(tostring(cd))
--[[Output
HL2DEMO
luajit: bad argument #1 to 'copy' (cannot convert 'int' to 'void *')
]]--
```

Summary:
Goal: Read integers and floats from binary data.
Expected output: A lua integer or float I can then convert to string.

Comment: You could also take this as an excuse to learn C and implement your own version of 5.3s `string.unpack` function  ;)

Comment: I have indeed pivoted to trying to learn C for this program, as even though the FFI solved my problem, I found it frustrating to try and create standalone executables with linked dependencies with LuaJIT/Lua. My new problem is that C sucks! Very unfun to learn and write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[string.unpack](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.unpack) does this for Lua 5.3, but there are some alternatives for LuaJIT as well. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50814550/1442917) (and other answers to the same question).

Comment: Thank you. I did do searching before but I could not find an answer on SO, probably because the title is not closely related to my issue.